# How to choose destaddress randomly in initialization file?

Tags: omnet++, inet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IybOz.png)
I'm using omnet++ to build a simple switch network based inet framework. In the initialization file, I want the host to randomly select a destination address each time, but it seems that I can only choose one destination address as the configuration.

Is there any syntax, function or other method to randomly select the destination address?  (BTW: I changed the destAddress type from string to volatile string in EtherAppClient model.)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

While in most cases adding the `volatile` modifier is not enough, in this particular case the c++ code is written in a way that it re-reads the parameter value each time it requires it (i.e. does not cache it) so adding `volatile` will indeed force the code to re-evaluate the expression on each send operation.

To get a random value from the destination I would combine `intuniform(1,8)` and any of the `get()`, `select()` or `choose()` methods (depending on the format of the destination lists), or could also use string manipulation like `"host"+string(intuniform(1,8))`